# How to increase line width of spline with ezdxf

Tags: python, ezdxf

This is how I am increasing the width for a lwpolyline with ezdxf. How do I do this with a spline?

```
    def line_example(self):

        width = 0.1

        self.msp.unit1.add_lwpolyline([(-0.5, 0.5, width, width),
                                       (-0.5, -0.5, width, width),
                                       (0.5, -0.5, width, width),
                                       (0.5, 0.5, width, width)])
        self.msp.add_blockref(
            'UNIT1',
            (0, 0),
            dxfattribs={
                'xscale': .3,
                'yscale': .5
            })
```

```
    def spline_example(self):
        fit_points = [(0, 0, 0), (750, 500, 0), (1750, 500, 0), (2250, 1250, 0)]
        spline = self.msp.add_spline(fit_points)
```

Answer (score 1):

`add_spline` returns a [Spline](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dxfentities/spline.html) object, which is a subclass of [DFXGraphic](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dxfentities/dxfgfx.html#common-graphical-dxf-attributes).

The [DFXGraphic](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dxfentities/dxfgfx.html#common-graphical-dxf-attributes) class has a `linewidth` attribute. So...

```
def spline_example(self):
    fit_points = [(0, 0, 0), (750, 500, 0), (1750, 500, 0), (2250, 1250, 0)]
    spline = self.msp.add_spline(fit_points)
    spline.linewidth = width
```